# Create correlated errors terms from existing variable

Tags: r

Let say I have a vector:

```
Q<-rnorm(50,mean=0,sd=30)
```

I would like to create 10 variables that are composed of `Q+error term` such that each of the 10 variables have correlated error terms resulting in a correlation between the 10 variables of say .8.

Normally I would create correlated variables using:

```
vars<-rmvnorm(n=10, mean=c(rep(0,50)),cov.mat, method="chol")
```

What happens if I add `Q+vars`. Do I get what I am looking for?

Comment: Have you tried it? Based on your code, I'm not entirely sure what you really want. Do you just want your resulting variables to have different means (ie `Q`)? Then your `vars` would be an error term only in the sense of an intercept only model. This can be done easily by using `mean=Q`; are you familiar w/ R's [recycling](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#The-recycling-rule)? If you wanted to generate a set of vectors such that each value w/i each variable is a draw from a normal (ie `Q`) + a draw from an error distribution (ie `vars`), the `n`s in those 2 commands must match.

Comment: I made a mistake, the n's were meant to be the same. please see my edit.

Comment: @user1723765, note that `Q` should have length==50, since `vars` has 10 vectors of length==50, stacked in a 10x50 matrix. Also the comment you added extrapolated the question, so I took the liberty to rollback your edit.

Answer (score 0):

No! Note that `rmvnorm` returns your 10 random vectors in the *rows* of a 10x50 matrix. So of you add `Q + vars`, R will recycle `Q` "column-wise" to get a  10x50 matrix. But you can get what you want using this:

```
t(t(vars)+Q)
```

whose rows are random observations of a multivariate normal density with `mean==Q` and variance-covariance matrix given by `cov.mat`.

Comment: what I would like to have is actually 50 vectors with 10 random numbers so that each of the 50 variables have a pre-specified correlation with each other.